# How to dichotomize a data set in R

Tags: r

I am brand new to R, and am attempting to dichotomize the third dimension (10x10) of the following data set:

http://www.stat.washington.edu/~hoff/courses/567/Data/monks

It looks like I should be able to run two loops for the rows and columns like this, but isn't working:

```
for (k in 1:10)
{ replace(k,1, k>1=1) }
```

This is my second day trying to figure out *R*, with no background except for a little *STATA* experience. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. It might help us help you if you can say a little more about what you understand "dichotomize" to mean. What is the output you expect? http://www.stat.washington.edu/~hoff/courses/567/Homework/hw2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

As the data is an array, i would coerce it to a `data.frame` before using a function. I'm not sure if this is the output format you would like in the end.

```
# Coerce to a `data.frame`
df <- as.data.frame(my_data)

# Apply a function to the columns that makes the variables binary (meaning if they are positive, its a 1, else # a 0). This is what `ifesle` does. For more info read: ?ifelse

res = apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0))
       ROMUL.like1 BONAVEN.like1 AMBROSE.like1 BERTH.like1 PETER.like1 LOUIS.like1 VICTOR.like1
ROMUL             0             0             1           0           1           0            0
BONAVEN           1             0             0           0           0           0            1
AMBROSE           1             1             0           0           0           0            0
BERTH             0             0             0           0           1           1            0
PETER             0             0             0           1           0           0            0
LOUIS             1             0             0           1           0           0            0
```